# how to save added text to new variable in navigator.notification.prompt?

Tags: javascript, java, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm new to phoneGap and I'm using navigator.notification.prompt in my code. I want to add IP Address (192.168.1.201) in prompt box, the added IP address should save to new variable and also check for that variable is null or not. 
Here is my code:

```
function config()
{    
    var ret =navigator.notification.prompt("Server Address : ",click me,"Server IP",["Ok","Cancel"],"");

    if (ret =='')
    {
        navigator.notification.alert("Plz enter the correct Ip Address");   
    }
    else
    {
        navigator.notification.alert("Ip address is saved for your mobile"
            localStorage.setItem("ipAddress",ret);
    }
}

function clickme()
{
    navigator.notification.alert("Ip address is saved for your mobile", null, "Server IP", "OK");
}
```

but I'm not able to save the entered IP address to variable ret and check for that variable is null or not. please help me in sorting out this problem

thanks

Comment: thanks @kingofzeal...

Comment: please help me anyone

Answer (score 0):

Plugin execution is async, you can't get the prompt result doing `var ret =navigator.notification.prompt` as you do on a browser

You'll have to change your code to work in an async way:

```
function config()
{
    navigator.notification.prompt("Server Address : ",clickme,"Server IP",["Ok","Cancel"],"");
}
```

When you click OK or Cancel, the clickme function will be called, passing a result variable that will have the number of the button clicked and the text entered on the prompt field:

```
function clickme(result)
{
    var ret = result.input1;
    if (ret =='')
    {
        navigator.notification.alert("Plz enter the correct Ip Address");
    }
    else
    {
        navigator.notification.alert("Ip address is saved for your mobile", null, "Server IP", "OK");
        localStorage.setItem("ipAddress",ret);
    }

}
```